# Filling in 'x' in a log function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

if $3^5=x$ (exponential equation) converts to log form gives $log_3x=5$

that makes sense.

$$
3^5 = 243 \Rightarrow x=243
$$

So if I take the log form again: $log_3x=5$ and replace $x$ with $243$. I then take the log of $243$, expecting to get $5$?? But instead, I get $2.3856$??

Can anyone explain?

Comment: $\log_3 {243} = 5$, as expected. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_3%28243%29

Comment: It looks like you took the log base 10, instead of the log base 3 as you should have.

Comment: I've edited your question to use the math formatting here.  The basic idea is that wrapping text in dollar signs (`$`) makes it format like math, braces `{}`  group things, `^` makes an exponent, and underscore `_` makes a subscript.  Common functions (e.g. $\log,\,\sin$,etc.) are prefaced with a slash.  You can right-click on any math text to see what the code was to make it look "fancy" `:)`

Comment: @JacobMayle You're correct, I took base 10 in my handheld calc... So now, I'm confused why the different bases don't work, but that's really, really abstract in my head. When you specify which base, it does work. I did this: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28243%29&a=*FunClash.log-_*Log10.Log-](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28243%29&a=*FunClash.log-_*Log10.Log-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @anorton, now I know for the future reference! Much appreciated!

Comment: if you use the "log" button to find out log it is base 10 so you can use this also to calculate a log having any base:$\log_a b=\dfrac {\log_{10}b}{\log_{10}a}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>log</kbd> button on a calculator takes the base-$10$ log of the number.  You want the base-$3$ log, so you either have to use the [*change of base formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) or use an fancier or online calculator like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_3%28243%29&t=ff3tb01).

To input a log of a certain base in Wolfram alpha, use the underscore `_`.  So, typing: `log_3(243)` gives the result  `5`. (Or, as pointed out below, the underscore isn't really needed.  I still like to use it for readability purposes.)

Comment: Good answer, but one comment: WA doesn't actually *require* the underscore, thus `log3` and `log_3` both work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the change of base formula in your calculator if you can only utilize base 10.

$$\frac{\log{243}}{\log{3}} = 5$$